Straightedge and compass in Gimp?
Are there technical drawing tools in Gimp, such as a straightedge and a compass, and a square?
For example, is it possible to construct a heptadecagon (a 17-sided, regular polygon) using basic tools like these in Gimp?
In particular, I want to make a 6-point perspective drawing using a stereographic projection, and to construct the perspective lines / arcs, I need a straightedge and a compass.
Edit: I discovered that Gimp's circle tool can act sort of like a compass if you hold down both control and shift. The only difference is that you can't draw just an arc but you always draw the complete circle, but if necessary, that can be circumvented by cutting up the circle and deleting the part that you don't want (which means that you may have to draw the circle in a separate layer, if you're not already doing that).

This question is similar to: divider or compass tool - or equivalent way - in Inkscape or Gimp?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

No.  GIMP isn't the right kind of software for this.  You would be better using CAD software for technical drawing.  GIMP is basically a photo editor - a raster image editor.  If you don't want to go down a full CAD route, other possbilities exist, such as vector image editors, like Inkscpe (also free and open source).  Inkscape has a polygon tool, although it has no 3D capabilities.

Also note that technical drawing/CAD questions are better suited to Engineering Stack Exchange.

@PaoloGibellini That question seems to be basically what I'm wondering. Thanks!

@BillyKerr What I want to do isn't a pure technical drawing. I want to use such tools only to construct the perspective guide curves, but then I want to draw the rest of my drawing by hand, probably with the paintbrush tool. Basically, I want to draw something like this, but using tools to make sure I get a stereographic projection specifically.

In that case, then something like Inkscape would probably work for you. It's possible to create curves and geometrical designs easily - see an example, then you can export as a PNG and open in software like GIMP to use as a guide for your drawing, or even just do the drawing in Inkscape itself.

@BillyKerr Nice, but does Inkscape have any tool that Gimp doesn't have that would help me here? I also discovered that Gimp's circle tool can act kind of like a compass if you hold down both control and shift, with the only difference that it always draws the entire circle, but that's okay. The only downside is that it doesn't snap to points (intersections, tangent points, circle centers, etc.), like you typically can do in CAD software, and which would be a nice feature to have, but that's probably well outside of the scope Gimp is designed for, and at least I got basically what I asked for.

Yes, it has many tools that GIMP doesn't have. Do a search for the youtube channel "Logos by Nick".  He has dozens of tutorials which show the capabilities of Inkscape.  There's too much to go into here. Inkscape is a very different tool to GIMP, so it's not really fair to compare them. They exist for different purposes.

Here's a very quick demo of using circles and snapping to object centres to create a design you could make with compasses.

@BillyKerr Oh, snap! That's made with Inkscape I suppose? Now I've got to check it out.

Yes it's made with Inkscape

There are several plugins/scripts to generate geometrical shapes. You won't create a 17-edges polygon with rule and compass, you will tell a script where the center and one vertex are and how many sides you want.

In general, perspective drawing is left to 3D programs, so support for tools that make it easier to do 3D perspective drawing by hand is rather lacking in the 2D apps.

Do you know if it's easy to write such a plugin yourself (given that you know how to program in C, which seems to be what the plugins are written in)? Also, do you know if Gimp has something similar to Krita's assistant tools, which let's you create guide lines for various purposes by placing control points? If so, maybe I can write my own such plugin specifically for a curvilinear perspective with stereographic projection (otherwise, I may use Krita instead, since Krita already has that possibility).

I don't know if I agree with you that perspective drawing generally is left to 3D programs, though. While 3D computer graphics excel in drawing things in perspective, there are many people who draw in perspective by hand, too. There are pros and cons with both choices, but mostly I think the people who draw in perspective by hand just like the look of hand-drawn images. That, or the fact that drawing something by hand goes much quicker than 3D modelling the same thing on a computer (at least for more organic subjects, I guess).

You can create guides in Gimp. You can also create paths, that can be shown but not rendered in the final drawing, and so can be used as guides when painting (then can even b used for "snapping"). Plugins can be written in C, but also in Python and Scheme.

I don't like the notion that many of you are selling that you shouldn't do your own 3d construction. You absolutely should all know how to do this., Why? Well for starters once you have a construction it relatively easy for you to draw things that would take you lots and lots of time to 3d model. But you can do that in 3d? Well sure but that's the exact same argument of you shouldn't draw but let AI do it.

@jooja I'm not saying that you shouldn't. I'm just saying that most people who want  a perspective drawing these days are going to use Blender or equivalent, so the incentive to add such help in 2D apps is low. Krita could be the exception, but Krita is more about creating/painting than Gimp.

@xenoid well my hypothesis is not that this isnt a needed feature. Its that people who develop drawing applications dont actually know how to draw so they have a bit naive onlook on what kinds of tools you would need. So you end up with tools needed for imaging, but end up short on tools that would actually be helpful for drawing. Why? well you see so many tools that have drawing features of varying maturity. But it isnt untill much much later in the process that tools start to develop features for usability drawing. it makes sense, drawing as a skill takes longer than learning how to program.

@xenoid Yes, but Gimp guides and paths are not quite the same thing as a compass. If you can write own plugins that can produce guide circles (which would be what you would use a compass for) then than could be an option for those who know how to program, but I think I'm leaning more towards using Krita now anyway if it is the better drawing tool out of the two (which it seems to be, according to both you and other sources).
